# Python caching in windows 10 using lru_cache

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I have a python program which runs slowly. I added cache using @lru_cache(maxsize=2056) decorator to increase the cache of my process, but when i run my code the consumed memory of my program is 260 MB in task manager (not 2 GB). Is it a limitation of windows 10 that does not permit high cache? 
I run my code using eclipse luna + pydev. The version of my python is 3.5.

Comment: Why should the Cache allocate 2056MB if it only needs 260? This is a maxsize that the Cache should not exceed.

Comment: yes, maybe it is the reason. but the speed of my code is not incresed, while this code is runnig in just 2 minutes in another system

Comment: unrelated suggestion. ensure that maxsize=2^x where x is a positive integer. lru_cache works significantly better when maxsize is a power of 2 (I'm not sure the exact reason why however).

Answer (score 0):

It can't be a limitation of Windows 10.
the `maxsize` parameter on @lru_cache indicates the maximum number of functions returns that will be saved on memory, depending of what you are caching, the size of the cache will vary.

So you are caching the 2056 most recent calls with different parameters between them.

According to docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

`If maxsize is set to None, the LRU feature is disabled and the cache can grow without bound. The LRU feature performs best when maxsize is a power-of-two.`

This will save all different functions calls in cache memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chaim. You are right. I checked my task manager again. the consumed memory is considered for python, not my eclipse. Now it is more than 1 GBs. So this is not the windows 10 limitation.